# How can I reference JFactory within a PHP class?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jfactory

##### In Joomla 3:

I'm writing a class to represent a semi-complex data structure. In that class, some methods need to access the app, dbo, document and user objects from JFactory.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
class Survey {
    use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
    
    private $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    private $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    private $db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

I'm getting an error on the line `private $app = JFactory::getApplication();`, the error is:

**Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in /*joomla path*/media/tmpl/classSurvey.php on line 46**

I've also tried to set it up inside the constructor, but I get the same error message:

```
function __construct($surveyID = -1) {
    $this->app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $this->doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $this->db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

Do I need to get these objects outside the class and pass them via the constructor?

*Forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this, but it seemed to be the only Stack Exchange site related to Joomla I could find.*

Thanks!

Comment: Your Joomla-related questions are 100% welcome here.  Thanks Sloan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USE statement should be before the Class statement, or outside the Class.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
...
class Survey {
```

These lines

```
private $app = JFactory::getApplication();
private $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
private $db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

are in the right place inside your class however they should be

```
private $app;
private $doc;
private $db;
```

and then your _constructor looks okay but JFactory is now Factory.

```
function __construct($surveyID = -1) {
    $this->app = Factory::getApplication();
    $this->doc = Factory::getDocument();
    $this->db = Factory::getDbo();
```

Having $app, $doc and $db as Private may cause conflicts with other code and so generally you see them as Public and not Private. Given your code appears to be in a template you may find they are already available to you and don't need to be created in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that "Constant expression contains invalid operations" is thrown if you ever try to set a class property using a variable.  Class properties declarations are set at compile time prior to variables having values in memory.  Hence you have to populate the values within the constructor.

```
class Survey {

    private $app = JFactory::getApplication(); // this is a fatal error
    private $resolved_prior_to_variables_having_values = 1; // this is fine

    // ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had a lot of trouble deciding which answer to check mark. Your answer and the one by Irata together solved my problem. Thanks!